# CWB encoding Corpus

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, corpus

According to the Corpus Work Bench, to encode a corpus i need to use the cwb-encode perl script

"encode the corpus, i.e. convert the verticalized text to CWB binary format with the cwb-encode tool. Note that the command below has to be entered on a single line." http://cogsci.uni-osnabrueck.de/~korpora/ws/CWBdoc/CWB_Encoding_Tutorial/node3.html

```
$ cwb-encode -d /corpora/data/example -f example.vrt -R /usr/local/share/cwb/registry/example -P pos -S s
```

when i tried it, it says the file is missing but i'm sure the file is in $HOME/corpora/data/example, the error was

```
$ cwb-encode -d /corpora/data/example -f example.vrt -R /usr/local/share/cwb/registry/example -P pos -S s
example.vrt: No such file or directory
Can't open input file example.vrt!
```

can anyone figure out why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about giving full path to `example.vrt`:

```
cwb-encode -d /corpora/data/example -f /corpora/data/example/example.vrt -R /usr/local/share/cwb/registry/example -P pos -S s
```

Comment: ahhh thanks plaes.... the instructions on the documentation was soo vague. at last i got pass it...

Comment: The example command is assuming the example.vrt file is in the directory you're running the command from.