# Extracting tuples with nltk?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Reading the documentation of nltk i found that is possible to extract tuples with `str2tuple()`. As an instance assume i have the following sentence(clearly is a much larger file):

```
sent = "pero pero CC " \
        "tan tan RG " \
        "antigua antiguo AQ0FS0 " \
        "que que CS " \
        "según según SPS00 " \
        "mi mi  DP1CSS " \
        "madre madre NCFS000"
```

I would like to extract a list of tuples, e.g.:

```
> ([antigua, AQ0FS0],[madre, NCFS000])
```

The female adjective tag `(AQ0FS0)` and the female noun tag `(NCFS000)`. Is this possible with `str2tuple()` or a better aproach could be using a regular expression?

This is what i have tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import nltk as nl

sent = "pero pero CC " \
              "tan tan RG " \
              "antigua antiguo AQ0FS0 " \
              "que que CS " \
              "según según SPS00 " \
              "mi mi  DP1CSS " \
              "madre madre NCFS000"

nl.tag.str2tuple(t) for t in sent.split()
```

Comment: I have a regex aproach, is it worth to put in the description of the question the actual script?

Comment: What does your file really look like? How are sentence boundaries indicated? Note that you can embed multiple lines in a single python literal string if you surround the whole thing with `"""(multiple lines)"""`

Comment: Also, the last line of your script would give you a generator in the right context. To see your code at work, write `result = list( nl.tag.str2tuple(t) for t in sent.split() )`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you have is a verticalized text file, aka as `.vrt` , see [CWB encoding Corpus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589684/cwb-encoding-corpus)

I guess the first column means the surface form of the word, the second refers to some sort of lemma and the third is the part-of-speech text.

First take a look at `csv` module, i find this tutorial helpful, http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/using-the-csv-module-in-python/

Let's say you have a tab-delimited file as such:

```
pero    pero    CC
tan tan RG
antigua antiguo AQ0FS0
que que CS
según   según   SPS00
mi  mi  DP1CSS
madre   madre   NCFS000
```

To read the file, sometimes people call it "to parse the file":

```
import csv

with open('test.txt', 'r') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    for line in reader:
        word, lemma, pos = line
        print word, lemma, pos
```

To get the `(word,pos)` tuple structure for the sentence, try:

```
import csv
sentences = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    for line in reader:
        word, lemma, pos = line
        sentences.append((word, pos))

print sentences
```

[out]:

```
[('pero', 'CC'), ('tan', 'RG'), ('antigua', 'AQ0FS0'), ('que', 'CS'), ('seg\xc3\xban', 'SPS00'), ('mi', 'DP1CSS'), ('madre', 'NCFS000')]
```

Comment: Thank you @alvas, probably i´ll do several string parsing like this. Would you recommend me to use this aproach or regex?

Comment: i have a .tag text, i all rady POS-tagged the corpus and the output looks like that.

Comment: regex or csv don't really matter, i guess, you can also `line.split('\t')`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're presumably interested in using your corpus with the NLTK: Assuming your file is stored in this format, you should read it in, parse it (using `str2tuple` or other simpler methods) and load it with `TaggedCorpusReader`. Then you can use all the standard NLTK corpus functions with it. You basically have two types of tags, part of speech and (presumably) word lemma. If this is what you're after, I can add more specific information to this answer.

Assuming your string actually includes a newline after each triple, the easy way to parse it into a list of tuples is like this:

```
sent = """pero pero CC
tan tan RG
antigua antiguo AQ0FS0
que que CS
según según SPS00
mi  mi DP1CSS
madre madre NCFS000"""

tuples = [ line.split() for line in sent.splitlines() ]
```

A detail: `split()` actually returns a list, not a tuple. If you need to use them as dictionary keys, replace `line.split()` with `tuple(line.split())`.